# Reading in excel files with wrapped headers onto pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I want to import excel sheets as data frames and export as csv. I need to do this for quite a few files. However, the headers of all files are arranged in two rows.

Thus, when I read the files, I get the headers as `Fuel Temp \n(Deg C)`,`Air Charge Temp \n(Deg C)` and so on.

How do I read these files into dataframes without the '\n'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you need [`str.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.replace.html):

```
df.columns = df.columns.str.replace('\n', '')
```

Comment: @hegdep - It is really data dependent problem, is possible share your excel file with no data only columns names? (maybe first row in excel)